# How to validate XML against DTD using Saxon from command line

Tags: xml, command-line, dtd, saxon

I have a library Saxon9ee.jar and I want to validate XML file against DTD schema located in external file (not inside XML) using Saxon9ee with command line interface.
I found out how to validate XML against XSD schema:

```
java -cp saxon9ee.jar com.saxonica.Validate -xsd:<XSD_file> -s:<XML_file> -xsdversion:1.1
```

But how can I do the same with DTD schema file?

Answer (score 4):

Validating against a DTD doesn't really involve Saxon at all, it's all done in the XML parser. But oddly, the Xerces parser is rather poor in terms of command line interfaces, so invoking it via Saxon is probably the most convenient way of doing it. Run the simplest possible query, with DTD validation enabled:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:. -s:source.xml -dtd:on
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how in your case validator will know that he needs to use DTD schema file and what file to use? This is external DTD schema file and XML file doesn't have a declaration with link to it. Does it automatically apply all DTD files in the folder or what?

Comment: I don't know of any way of validating an XML file against a DTD if the XML file does not have a DOCTYPE declaration referring to the DTD. You can redirect the DTD reference to a different location, but if there's a way of supplying a DTD reference externally, I don't know of it.